# Remove newlines from a JSMin minified file and parsing error on IF condition

Tags: php, javascript, newline, minify

I'm trying to minify on the fly a javascript file with php and JSMin.
Everything works fine, but when I try to remove newlines

```
$jsMinifiedClean = str_replace( array("\r","\n"),"",$jsMinified);
```

I get a javascript parse error.
After a quick search in the code I found the problem:

```
if( condition ) statement
else statement;
```

The "if" condition doesn't have the " ; " at the end of the line.

Why with a manual YUI compression of the code I get no error?
Is the semicolon really mandatory at the end of the if to avoid the problem in compressing with JSMin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the semicolon really mandatory at the end of the if to avoid the problem in compressing with JSMin?

It is if you remove the newline. By default, JSMin does *not* remove the newline for exactly this reason, the horror that is [automatic semicolon insertion](http://es5.github.com/#x7.9). From the [JSMin page](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html):

> It is more conservative in omitting linefeeds, because linefeeds are sometimes treated as semicolons. A linefeed is not omitted if it precedes a non-ASCII character or an ASCII letter or digit or one of these characters:
>
> ```
> \ $ _ { [ ( + -
> ```
>
> and if it follows a non-ASCII character or an ASCII letter or digit or one of these characters:
>
> ```
> \ $ _ } ] ) + - " '
> ```

If you then remove the newline, you're taking it upon yourself to be sure that the newline isn't significant because of ASI.